# I am constantly facing an error while working with pip in python 3.8.0a2

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I use pip for anything, be it update or installing of libraries, then i get the following error:-

```
C:\Users\Admin>pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe
\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_internal\build_env.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_internal\cli\spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.rich.console import (
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\rich\console.py", line 39, in <module>
    from typing import Literal, Protocol, runtime_checkable
ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (c:\users\admin\appdata\
local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\typing.py)
```

My computer is Windows 7 and earlier I had python 3.7 which worked all right, but later just for the purpose of Tensorflow I downloaded 3.8.0a2 and I have got this error. While using 3.7 I never faced an issue. And the issue is only with pip rest all my code goes good.

I updated pip from 19 to latest version but it just doesn't help. I had downloaded a few libraries back in 3.7 and now the programs that were dependent upon those libraries are not working.

Comment: I suggest upgrading to Python 3.9 or 3.10, not using an old alpha release

Comment: `3.8.0a2` is a very very early development version of 3.8. Most likely Literal hadn't been added yet.

Comment: See latest releases at https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/